# MATLAB extractHOGFeatures returns empty struct

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, edge-detection

I am working on a Computer Vision project of extracting the digits from an image. After a bit of pre-processing, following is my image:

[image]

I performed sobel edge detection and some other steps and extracted the digits from the image. Now when I apply extractHOGFeatures on the digits, I am getting an empty struct for one of the digits. It doesn't happen with most of the images, just a few.

The code works for `0` but not for `1` and there is no specific pattern in the occurrence of the digits, sometimes none of the digits get features.

[image]
[image]

I cannot see a reason why the code wouldn't work for one segment of an image and not the other. Can anyone please help? Thanks!

Comment: Why has this question been downvoted?

Comment: I did not downvote it, but I'm guessing it is because you don't have any code. Please include your commented code with an explanation of what you expect and how it differs from what you get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the default cell size for extractHOGFeatures is **[8x8]** while some of the extracted images were just [6x6].